# Resize the UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, resize, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is it possible to change the size of an UITabBarItem? I'm not talking about the image inside the UITabBarItem, but the UITabBarItem itself.

For example if you have four UITabBarItems in a UITabBar, is it then possible to "merge" the two UITabBarItems in the center of the UITabBarItem (so that you would have a large UItabBarItem in the middle of the UITabBar and two smaller UITabItems on each side)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible using any standard functions in `UITabBar`, however you could use some other [custom solution](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)